# Redshift INET_NTOA

Tags: amazon-redshift

It's pretty straight forward - I'm wondering if there's a function that will calculate IP address from a number, equivalent to `INET_NTOA` in mySQL.

I'm aware I can calculate it, but the question remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing out of the box, but you can write your own [UDF in Python](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html) for that if you want, if you really need a function, or a simple expression in a query.

Comment: thanks. i'm aware of this and i resolved the issue by division, modulo and multiplication. i was hoping there's something else though.

Answer (score 0):

Update: inet_ntoa is available in redshift